# Rails- changing member route name without appending parent name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following routes defined:

```
  resources :scenes do
    member do
      match 'files' => 'scenes#files', via: :get, as: 'scene_files'
    end
  end
```

I'd like to be able to refer to the nested route as `scene_files_path`, but Rails insists on adding an extra `scene` to the path so what I end up with is `scene_files_scene_path`. How can I get the named route I am looking for?

Answer (score 2):

I started to simplify your member block with

```
resources :scenes do
  get :files, :as => :scene_files, :on => :member
end
```

then I stumbled upon

```
resources :scenes do
  get :files
end
```

which produces:

```
> rake routes
  scene_files GET       /scenes/:scene_id/files(.:format)     scenes#files
       scenes GET       /scenes(.:format)                     scenes#index
             POST       /scenes(.:format)                     scenes#create
    new_scene GET       /scenes/new(.:format)                 scenes#new
   edit_scene GET       /scenes/:id/edit(.:format)            scenes#edit
        scene GET       /scenes/:id(.:format)                 scenes#show
              PUT       /scenes/:id(.:format)                 scenes#update
           DELETE       /scenes/:id(.:format)                 scenes#destroy
```

only one problem, the param key is `:scene_id` instead of :`id`

Comment: I guess having `:scene_id` is OK. Is there a more verbose way of writing the route that would give the desired name and use `:id`?